# How to optimize this UML diagram class for document generation

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

According this class diagram, whose purpose is to model the generation of several types of documents:

[image]

bigger size available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/heub3dmh7sznkih/document_generation.png?dl=0

The client code will make use of the DocumentGenerator class, which is a Document factory, describing the type of document needed, and the service (the inspection is optional, only required for dispatch documents).

I'm struggling with the classes coloured in red. If all the insurance companies used the same document models for invoices, estimates, etc, this wouldn't be much of a problem. But there's one company that needs a different dispatch document model to be printed, and this is very likely to happen with more companies, not only with the dispatch but also with the rest of the documents.

Guess what would happen if I specialized each of the document subclasses for each company? It would be a nightmare of code duplication.

Two design patterns (**strategy** or **decorator**) might meet my requirement in order to favor composition over inheritance, but I can't figure out how to capture the idea.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

This is a link to the XMI file of this diagram, in case you want to use it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1l5ohdnojvvkze/documents_generation.xmi?dl=0

**EDIT:**

I get an idea of how to do it. Maybe no new class would be necessary. The implementation (PHP):

```
// DocumentGenerator Class
class DocumentGenerator {

    const INVOICE_TYPE  = 1;
    const ESTIMATE_TYPE = 2;
    const DISPATCH_TYPE = 3;

    private __construct() {}

    public function getInstance($type, Service $service)
    {
        switch($type) {
            case self::ESTIMATE_TYPE:
                $document = new Estimate($service);
                break;
            case self::DISPATCH_TYPE:
                $document = new Dispatch($service);
                break;
            default:
            case self::INVOICE_TYPE:
                $document = new Invoice($service);
        }
        return $document;
    }
}


// Document Class
abstract class Document {

    protected $service;

    public function __construct(Service $service) 
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    abstract protected function show();
    // ....
}


// Invoice Class
class Invoice extends Document {

    const PATH_SEGMENT = 'invoice';

    public function show()
    {
        // the key point
        $this->view->setPath(self::PATH_SEGMENT . '/' . $service->getCompanyName());
        $this->view->create();   
    }

    // ...
}

// creating an invoice, no matter the company
$document = DocumentGenerator::getInstance(DocumentGenerator::INVOICE_TYPE, $service);
$document->show();
```

The company name and the document type would lead to the proper template to use by the view. I'm still not sure if this is a good solution, since I have hardcoded naming conventions to reach a particular template file.

Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different requirements you are likely to need different implementations. If you have some general format of the document you can create some superclass covering that document. And if you have different implementations for different companies then you need to either implement completely different Dispatch/Estimate/Invoice classes our you find some generalization (which would enable code-reuse). In any case: different requirements lead to different code. I would not see how this would lead to a nightmare. An alternative is always (though in most cases not possible due to blockheads) it to persuade or rule some common document format.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get the point of what I want to do. I think it would be a waste of time and code duplication if I had to create as many classes as Company1Invoice, Company2Invoice, Company3Invoice..., Company1Dispatch, Company2Dispatch, and so on. The different implementation would rely on different templates for each document based on it's type and the company it's made for, since all the companies would share the same data for each document type. So that's not the problem. I need to somehow properly connect the document-type/company pairs to their corresponding templates.

Comment: You could use a generic Document class and bind to the different implementations using the company.

Comment: Could you describe that in more detail?

Comment: Instead of using a raw Document class you can create a generic class. The parameter to bind the class (thus creating a real class) would be the company. That would take the complexity out of the diagram (and model structure). You could let the above diagram stand alone and create another one that just focuses on binding the generics to the different companies.

Comment: As a side note: the aggregation of company in service and then in document does not seem to make sense. I'd use a simple association.

Comment: I can't see it clearly yet what you mean. As for the last comment, I interpreted that a document cannot live without a service, and it must store a reference to the service during it's lifetime, so the former is an intrinsic part of the latter, but a service can live without the document class (so it's not full composition). Anyway there are uncompleted features in the diagram since I wanted to focus on the problem.

Comment: I avoid the use of aggregation since it focuses on implementation details. And your level seems to be still above. Sure, it's a bit opinion based and discussing it here would lead us too far away.

Comment: Did you mean something like I do in the "Edit" part? I'm still not certain if the implemention should work without problems because of the hard-coding. Or following this naming convention as a trade-off should be enough.

Comment: Yes and no. An abstract class is just one that need a few tidbits to get implemented. A generic class additionally has parameters (you could say a parametrized generalization). Naming conventions are not bad per se. Ruby on Rails has extended naming conventions and it's working not too bad in the end. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587305/interfaces-inheritance-and-genrics-in-uml-class-diagram