# UML Class Diagrams - notation for extending a Generic, Abstract class?

Tags: java, generics, uml, abstract-class

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786771/uml-class-diagram-and-generics) stack overflow post describing something similar, but this implies that the Abstract Generic class is being extended into another abstract class with the template parameter specified and then extended into the class we want.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/323Dp.png) is what I have, and I definitely don't think that this is correct.

Below is the code that needs to be modeled.

`public abstract class Board<T>`

`public class TopBoard extends Board<BottomBoard>`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following describes what you want. The templated type is *bound* to the class BottomBoard (*see* Template Bindings).

[image]